# Как собрать exe через jpackage из проекта maven?

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, maven

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пользоваться данной утилитой правильно? Возможно, я просто плохо ищу, но неделю уже этот момент меня стопорит. Проект у меня на maven, JavaFX приложение для работы с excel таблицами. Если нужна структура проекта – приложу или могу ссылку на гитхаб скопировать. Спасибо за ответ заранее!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я в свое время для этих целей (именно maven + javafx) нашел скрипт [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX) (сам скрипт в виде 3-х вариантов для разных ОС в каталоге jpackagefx-main). Это самое удобное решение для модульных решений.